# jQuery / JS animation screwed up (Firefox/IE)

Tags: jquery, browser

edit:

Problem seems not to be limited to IE, see my answer post below for a testcase.

Hello, I am rotating between 3 different background images on a logo:

```
$(function() {

    function Animate_2() {

        $("div#bg1" ).animate({opacity: 0 }, 2000);
        $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);

        setTimeout(Animate_3, 5000);

    }

    function Animate_3() {

        $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
        $("div#bg3").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);

        setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);

    }

    function Animate_1() {

        $("div#bg3").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
        $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);

        setTimeout(Animate_2, 5000);

    }

    /* Start it */
    setTimeout(Animate_2, 5000);

});
```

bg1 to bg3 have the following styles:

```
div#bg1 {
    height:             159px;
    width:              800px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    background-image:   url('images/bg_1.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:           relative;
    z-index:            3;
}


div#bg2 {
    height:             159px;
    width:              800px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    background-image:   url('images/bg_2.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:           relative;
    z-index:            2;
    margin-top:         -159px;
}

div#bg3 {
    height:             159px;
    width:              800px;
    margin-left:        auto;
    margin-right:       auto;
    background-image:   url('images/bg_3.jpg');
    background-repeat:  no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    position:           relative;
    z-index:            1;
    margin-top:         -159px;
}
```

IE does it just fine for the first animation, bg1 nicely fades out while bg2 fades in... After that first perfect transition it screws up in IE (all versions!) while it works just fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

In IE the image does change, but it does not properly fade out / in...

When running it through IETester, I continuously get the hour glass cursor as if it is downloading the background image on the fly...

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What to you mean by "it screws up"? Does the animation stop, or does something else go wrong?

Comment: The image does change, but it does not properly fade out / in

Comment: Can you check what happens when you start out with Animate_3() instead of Animate_2() ?

Comment: I have a testcase with just 2 images, which should do exactly the identical thing (just flipped), but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this: `

```
        $(function()
        {setTimeout(dostuff, 1000);});
         function dostuff(){
  $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 100}, 1000).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000);
  $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 0}, 1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000).animate({opacity: 100}, 1000).animate({opacity:100}, 1000).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);dostuff()}
```

`

One of the things about jquery is that you can chain stuff. Doing it like this is lest complicated and easier to follow and debug I think.

Answer (score 0):

I have now managed to produce this behavior on Firefox, with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            div#bg1 {
                height:             159px;
                width:              800px;
                margin-left:        auto;
                margin-right:       auto;
                background-image:   url('images/bg1.jpg');
                background-repeat:  no-repeat;
                background-position:center center;
                position:           relative;
                z-index:            3;
            }
            div#bg2 {
                height:             159px;
                width:              800px;
                margin-left:        auto;
                margin-right:       auto;
                background-image:   url('images/bg2.jpg');
                background-repeat:  no-repeat;
                background-position:center center;
                position:           relative;
                z-index:            2;
                margin-top:         -159px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function Animate_2() 
            {
                $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);
                $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
                setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
            }

            function Animate_1() 
            {
                $("div#bg1").animate({opacity: 0  }, 2000);
                $("div#bg2").animate({opacity: 100}, 2000);
                setTimeout(Animate_2, 5000);
            }

            $(function()
            {
                /* Start cycle */
                setTimeout(Animate_1, 5000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bg1"></div>
        <div id="bg2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

All is fine and dandy at first animate, but it just changes the image (without animation!) at animate_2() ...